# how to display sub links by clicking an item angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am beginner with angularjs, so i have download a menu and i dont know how to make it work with angularjs. when i click on items how can i show their sub links?

itemController.js

```js
app
    .controller('itemList', function($scope, itemProvider){


     $scope.items = [];
     $scope.sublinks = null;

      

     itemProvider.getItems().success(function(data){
     $scope.items  = data;
     alert("ll"+$scope.items[0].sublinks[0].title);
   });

    $scope.showSublinks = function(item){

        $scope.sublinks = item.sublinks;    
    }

    });
```

the following code works fine

menu.html

```html
<div id="menu">
            <nav>
                <h2><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>All Categories</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li >
                        <a ><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>{{items[0].title}}</a>
                        <h2><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>{{items[0].title}}</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li >
                                <a><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>{{items[0].sublinks[0].title}}</a>
                                <h2><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>{{items[0].sublinks[0].title}}</h2>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                        <a ><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>{{items[1].title}}</a>
                        <h2><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>{{items[1].title}}</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li >
                                <a><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>{{items[1].sublinks[0].title}}</a>
                                <h2><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>{{items[1].sublinks[0].title}}</h2>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div-->
```

but the problem is when i add the directive ng-repeat

```html
 <div id="menu">
            <nav>
                <h2><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>All Categories</h2>
                <ul>

                      <li class="main btn" ng-repeat="item in items">



                        <a  ng-click="showSubMenu(item)" ng-model="master"> <!--i class="fa fa-laptop" ></i--> 

                       {{item.title}} 
                       <img class="item_icon" src="{{item.icon}}"></a>
                        <h2><i class="fa "></i> {{item.title}} </h2>

                                <ul>
                                    <li class="sub " ng-repeat="sublink in sublinks">
                                    <a class="btn alignhref">{{sublink.title}}</a>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                       </li>

                        </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

routing.js

```js
app
    .config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/items', {
                    templateUrl:'js/app/views/item/menu.html',
                    controller:'itemList'
                });
    }]
)
```

Comment: simplest solution is start with  css `:hover` rules. If you want clciks go back when you know a bit more

Answer (score 0):

I'm Beginner in the use of angularjs too.

Chek this
http://jsfiddle.net/f8ea6/293/

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" ng-app="rgMenu" ng-controller="itemList">
<nav>
    <h2>All Categories</h2>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <a ng-click="showSubMenu(item)">
                <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
            </a>
            <ul ng-if="item.sublinks">
                <li ng-repeat="sublink in sublinks">
                    <a>{{sublink.title}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("rgMenu",[]); app.controller('itemList', function($scope){ $scope.items = [ {"title":"Google", "description":"Google Search Engine"}, {"title":"Yahoo", "description":"Yahoo Search Engine",
    "sublinks":[ 
        {"title":"Yahoo", "href":"http://yahoo.com/", "target":"_blank" },
        {"title":"Sports", "href":"http://sports.yahoo.com/", "target":"_blank" },
        {"title":"News", "href":"http://news.yahoo.com/", "target":"_blank" }
    ]},
{"title":"Bing", "description":"Bing Search Engine"},
{"title":"Dogpile", "description":"Dogpile Search Engine"}
];

$scope.sublinks = null;
$scope.showSubMenu = function(item){
    $scope.sublinks = item.sublinks;    
}});
```

Maybe can help you.